# Why do I get the failed to load with Java version 1.7.0_45 with Eclipse with JBoss modules used

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

[image: Java Error when using JBOSS]

The main problem has to do with the Eclipse.ini settings in your Eclipse startup path such as my file is here: "O:\Dump\XFer\Apps\java\eclipse\mars\eclipse.ini"

The next image is the error I was getting.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason has to do with the JDK settings for Eclipse. 
You can try and change the Build/Workspace JRE with Eclipse, but it will not fix the problem.

What you have to do is Make sure your Eclipse ini has the correct path for the "JDK" is set in your eclipse startup setting.

i.e "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/javaw.exe"

It is probably a good idea to make sure your environment variable(s) for Java_Home are set correctly as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The default java in my path was C:\Windows\System32\java.exe (Java 7 installed as public JRE). I renamed this executable then added Java 8 to the PATH explicitly and problem was solved!